# $\forall n , \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k b_{n-k}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

- $(a_n)_n >0$ and decreasing
- $(b_n)_n >0$
- $ B_n= \sum_{k=0}^n b_k$
- $\forall n , \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k b_{n-k}=1$

1. If we suppose $\exists (m_n)_n$ for $n$ large : $B_{m_n -n} \sim B_n$ and $B_{m_n}-B_{m_n -n}\to 0$, we want to prove that $a_n \sim \frac1{B_n}$
2. We suppose $ \exists \, C >0, b_n \sim \frac C{n}$ we want to find a particular $(m_n)_n$ such that $a_n\sim \frac1{C \ln n}$

---

My attempt :

1.

$
\begin{align*}
 \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}&=1 \\
 &\geq \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n a_n b_{n-k} \\
 &= a_n \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n b_{n-k} \\
&=a_n \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n b_k \\
&=a_n B_n \\
a_n &\leq \frac1{B_n}\\
\end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^m a_k b_{m-k}&=1\\
&= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k b_{m-k} + \displaystyle\sum_{k=n}^{m}   a_k b_{n-k} \\
&\leq a_0  \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_{m-k} + a_n  \displaystyle\sum_{k=n}^{m}b_{m-k} \\
&=a_n B_{m-n}+a_0 (B_m-B_{m-n})\\
\end{align*}
$

$1 \leq a_n B_{m-n}+a_0 (B_m-B_{m-n})$

$\dfrac{B_n}{B_{m-n}} (1-a_0 (B_m - B_{m-n}))\leq a_n B_n \leq 1$

We choose $m=m_n$ and we obtain $\boxed{a_n B_n \to 1}$

2.

$B_n \sim C \ln n$